# Gathering pageviews MySQL layout

Tags: mysql

Hey, does anyone know the proper way to set up a MySQL database to gather pageviews? I want to gather these pageviews to display in a graph later. I have a couple ways mapped out below.

**Option A:**
Would it be better to count pageviews each time someone visits a site and create a new row for every pageview with a time stamp. So, 50,000 views = 50,000 rows of data.

**Option B:**
Count the pageviews per day and have one row that counts the pageviews. every time someone visits the site the count goes up. So, 50,000 views = 1 row of data per day. Every day a new row will be created.

Are any of the options above the correct way of doing what I want? or is there a better more efficient way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Option C** would be to parse access logs from the web server. No extra storage needed, all sorts of extra information is stored, and even requests to images and JavaScript files are stored.

..

However, if you just want to track visits to pages where you run your own code, I'd definitely go for **Option A**, unless you're expecting extreme amounts of traffic on your site.

That way you can create overviews per hour of the day, and store more information than just the timestamp (like the visited page, the user's browser, etc.). You might not need that now, but later on you might thank yourself for not losing that information.
If at some point the table grows too large, you can always think of ways on how to deal with that.

Comment: I do plan on having lots of traffic, say about 2 million per month which worries me about how large the db will get fairly quickly. I also plan to have user's browser and other information in different tables which will only be added once(unique) to the db per person as apposed to just counting each impression.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about how your pageviews vary with time in a day, option A keeps that info (though you might still do some bucketing, say per-hour, to reduce overall data size -- but you might do that "later, off-line" while archiving all details). Option B takes much less space because it throws away a lot of info... which you might or might not care about. If you don't know whether you care, I think that, in doubt, you should keep more data rather than less -- it's reasonably easy to "summarize and archive" overabundant data, but it's NOT at all easy to recover data you've aggregated away;-). So, aggregating is riskier...

If you do decide to keep abundant per-day data, one strategy is to use multiple tables, say one per day; this will make it easiest to work with old data (summarize it, archive it, remove it from the live DB) without slowing down current "logging". So, say, pageviews for May 29 would be in PV20090529 -- a different table than the ones for the previous and next days (this does require dynamic generation of the table name, or creative uses of `ALTER VIEW` e.g. in cron-jobs, etc -- no big deal!). I've often found such "sharding approaches" to have excellent (and sometimes unexpected) returns on investment, as a DB scales up beyond initial assumptions, compared to monolithic ones...